# alternative for doctrine deprecated ping()

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-dbal

`Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::ping()`

[is marked as `@deprecated`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.12.x/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php#L2079)

I found [this commit](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/commit/e603a2e2333e043b9bba081dfaa2eda88814f478#diff-425f50e688c77962b97e5fd1f9803a6d9ffa9bf260ba12391f73b2aab14914ee) that introduced it but no info about successor for this method was given.

I would like to know what is expected alternative for this functionality.

Should I just rely on `isConnected()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dug a bit deeper, and found this
[pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/4119)

The author of this change says:

> What is the alternative to ensure the connection is not lost due to a connection timeout, so we can safely execute our actual query?

> There's no way to ensure that it's not lost. Even if the query you use to probe the connection succeeds, there's no guarantee that the real query will.

> Or is the solution to execute a dummy query and catch the ConnectionLost exception?

> See the above. The solution is to catch the ConnectionLost exception and handle it depending on the query. E.g. it is safe to re-execute a SELECT but isn't safe to re-execute an INSERT w/o first checking the current state of the database (the connection may fail after the row has been inserted).

So, calling just a `isConnected()` is not very reliable, and you need to execute some kind of real query, for example: `SELECT 1;` Hope this will help you!